# limit superior of a function at a point

Tags: real-analysis

I see a notation $\lim \sup_{t \to x}f(t)$ in one analysis book. I am aware of limit superior of a sequence, but here many sequences can converge to $x$. Confused with the notation.

Answer (score 0):

Look at this Wikipedia article on the [limit supremum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_superior_and_limit_inferior) underneath the heading of "Functions from metric spaces to metric spaces."

Comment: yes, but the limit may not in general exist. For example, the Dirichlet function.

Comment: In the extended real numbers, $\limsup$ and $\liminf$ always exist. The limit exists if and only if the two are equal. In your example, the limit supremum around any point will always be $1$, while the infimum will always be $0$.